# How do I import text from a user generated .txt-file to a div with PHP?

Tags: php, html, flash, text-files

I've made an Ecard using Flash and Dreamweaver. On the Ecard is a form to fill out, your name, your email, a comment, and the name and email to the person you are sending the ecard to. [(http://ornryd.com/test/playfulform/)](http://ornryd.com/test/playfulform/)
When you push the "Submit"-button it sends an email to the receiver, and it creates a .txt file on my server with the info.

The .txt-file has a unique name generated by:

```
$mailCount  = $_POST['me_count'];
$senderName = $_POST['me_name'];
$senderEmail= $_POST['me_email'];
$senderComm = nl2br($_POST['me_com']);
$date       = date("l jS F H:i:s");
$ToSubject  = "Email From $senderName via $webname";
$EmailBody  = "";
$emailCount = 0;


$CreateEcard = date(U);
$filename = $CreateEcard.".txt";
$senderName = stripslashes($FromName);
$senderComm = stripslashes($senderComm);
$id = stripslashes($id);

$Today = (date ("l dS of F Y ( h:i:s A )",time()));

$Created="Ecard Created on $Today";

$EcardNum = $EcardSelect;

$EcardText = "&senderName=$senderName&FromEmail=$FromEmail&Comment=$senderComm&Created=$Created";


$fp = fopen( "./formText/$filename","w"); 
fwrite($fp, $EcardText, 10000); 
fclose( $fp );
```

In the email there's a link to "page2" where I want the COMMENT from the form to display in a  or in a flash-text field, 
[(http://www.ornryd.com/test/player/index.php)](http://www.ornryd.com/test/player/index.php)

The problem is that I don't know how to import the user generated text in the .txt-file to a div on page 2.

I hope you understand what I want to do. If not, I can try to describe the things you don't understand a bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to send the filename in the link as a param. And then your PHP file will need to read that param, and open the appropriate file.

something along the likes of

the link would be 
http://www.ornryd.com/test/readcard?file=afilename.txt

and your PHP would look for it

```
$filename = isset($_GET['file']) ? $_GET['file'] : '';
$card = '';
if (file_exists($filename)) {
   $card = file_get_contents($filename);
}
```

now you have the card contents as a variable, you can display it wherever you want.

**NOTE** This is only an example. A few things you have to keep in mind is

1. This will allow people to look at other files unless you send some kind of security token (people can change the file to look at someone else's card)
2. You should be sanitizing the filename bit so that the path of the file always points only to the directory you want. So remove stuff like '../' that is in the path.

Comment: Ok thank you John, the link looks like **http://www.ornryd.com/test/player/index.php?EcardText=1298455911** at the moment. So i should just be able to insert the php-code u just wrote to the div inside index.php?

Comment: Yeah, that code in index.php with the params changed will do the trick. Not the points I made about security. If it's a test app, no worries

Comment: Thank you John. You just made my day!

Comment: NP. If it solved your question, please mark this question as answered by ticking the big checkmark. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your sending a link then include the `$CreateEcard` in the URL to find the right one e.g. `blah.php?file=12345`

In your `blah.php` make sure you check that `$_GET['file']` is a number (`intval`) then use `file_exists` to check `$_GET['file'] . ".txt"` exists and then run [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to retrieve the contents of the text file.

Comment: Do i write "$CreateEcard" in the $_GET['file'] tag? or how should the div-tag look like? I can't get this to work, the link in the email looks like this: [link](http://www.ornryd.com/test/player/index.php?EcardText=1298455911)

Comment: put the PHP code that retrieves the file within the HTML block you want it to appear in, you can mix PHP and HTML just make sure you open and close the PHP tags